# How to execute a function inside of a "Do While" in php without losing the variable

Tags: php, function, while-loop

This "do while" give me the results of a specific table.

```
do {
comprobe($row_DatosConsulta['strCod']);
    ?>
    <tr class="edit">
          <td class="text-center"> <?php  echo $row_DatosConsulta['strCod']; ?> </td>
          <td  class="text-center"> <?php echo $row_DatosConsulta['strNombre'] ?> <?php echo $row_DatosConsulta['strApellido'] ?> </td>
          <td  class="text-center"> <?php echo $row_DatosConsulta['strMedidor'] ?> </td>
          <td  class="text-center"> <?php echo ObtenerDeuda($row_DatosConsulta['intDeuda']) ?></td>
          <td  class="text-center">
} while ($row_DatosConsulta = $Result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC));
```

my problem is that when i try to use the function "comprobe" (a function that is in another page, but that page are included in the actual page) there is an error that appears, "Undefined variable" so i think that the  "do while" is not sending the name to the function, and in that order, the function cant work.

I need to execute a function with all the data that generate the "do while"... for example, if there is 30 names generated by the "do while" of the table, I need to execute 30 times that function with one per one of the names.
so my question is, how could i do that?

actually I'm using SQLITE3, and my function is the next one

```
function actualizardeudasusu(){
    $bd = new SQLite3('my_datebase.db');


$DatosConsulta = ("SELECT * FROM tblDeudas WHERE strCod='".$Codigo."' ");   
$Result = $bd->query($DatosConsulta)or die("Error in query: <span 
style='color:red;'>$query</span>");

$row_DatosConsulta = $Result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

echo $DatosConsulta;


$CONTADOR = (" PRAGMA table_info(tblDeudas); ");
$ResultCont = $bd->query($CONTADOR)or die("Error in query: <span             
style='color:red;'>$query</span>");
 $conteoprevio = $ResultCont->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

   $comprobaciondedeuda = 0;
   $number = 0;

   do {
   $number++;
    ${"mes".$number} = $conteoprevio['name'];
    if ($row_DatosConsulta[${"mes".$number}] != 'pagado'){
        $comprobaciondedeuda = 1;
                    }
            }
    while ($conteoprevio = $ResultCont->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC));


if ($comprobaciondedeuda == 1){

$updateSQL = "UPDATE tblafiliacion SET 
                        intDeuda='1'
 WHERE strCod='".$codigo."' " ;
$Result = $bd->query($updateSQL)or die("Error in query: <span 
style='color:red;'>$query</span>");

} else {
$updateSQL = "UPDATE tblafiliacion SET 
                        intDeuda='0',
 WHERE strCod='".$codigo."' " ;
$Result = $bd->query($updateSQL)or die("Error in query: <span 
 style='color:red;'>$query</span>");
    }


  }
```

Comment: Why not just while? Seems like it's probably undefined the first iteration because you haven't fetched a row yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `do while` loop is not a correct solution.

How does your `do-while` woork for the first time? You enter `do` body and try to use `$row_DatosConsulta`. But `$row_DatosConsulta` is **not defined**. Why? Because it will be defined **later** in `while`-check.

So, instead `do-while` use `while`:

```
while ($row_DatosConsulta = $Result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    comprobe($row_DatosConsulta['strCod']);
    // do other  stuff here
}
```